# Generic return types - why can't I do this?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, return-type

Consider the snippet below. I understand how overriding works with regard to generic types, and why the return type `List<String>` (for example) is permitted to override `List<? extends Object>`. However, I am not entirely clear why a statements such as 1 and 2 fail to compile...should not inheritance apply here as well?

```
public class Generics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A instance = new B();
        X instance2 = new Y();

        Map<String, String> map = instance2.getMap(); // 1
        List<String> list = instance.getList();       // 2
    }
}

class A {

    List<? extends Object> getList() {

        return null;
    }
}

class B
        extends A {

    List<String> getList() {

        return new LinkedList<String>();
    }
}

class X {

    Map<String, ? extends Object> getMap() {

        return null;
    }
}

class Y
        extends X {

    @Override
    Map<String, String> getMap() {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know there has been answers already, but can you post the compiler error, please ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I get a general static type check error (i.e. "can't convert from List<? extends Object> to List<String>).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> map = instance2.getMap(); // 1
```

The compiler sees a call to `X.getMap()` which has a return type of `Map<String, ? extends Object>`. This is not convertible to `Map<String, String>`. It doesn't matter that `instance2` is of type `Y` at runtime; this is pure compile-time static type checking that's failing.

```
List<String> list = instance.getList();       // 2
```

The same reasoning applies. The compile-time type of `instance` is `A`, and `A.getList()` returns a `List<? extends Object>` which is incompatible with `List<String>`.

Mind you, it's not an issue specific to generics. This would also fail to compile for the same reason:

```
class A { Object getObject(); }
class B extends A { String getObject(); }

A a = new B();
String s = a.getObject();
```

If you want it to work then you need to give the compiler some extra help. Either by casting to the sub-class:

```
String s = ((B) a).getObject();
```

Or by casting the return value:

```
String s = (String) a.getObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

polymorphism doesn't work backwards.

What if you tried that with a  different class that extended `X`, but it returned to you a \

```
Map<String, NonString>
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getMap` on `X` (since `instance2` is referrer through `X`) which is defined to return `Map<String, ? extends Object>` hence the issue.

If you change your call as (typecast `instance2` to `Y` before calling `getMap()`):

```
   Map<String, String> map = ((Y)instance2).getMap(); // 1
```

it should work as your `instance2` is still of type `Y`.